# Go back to the scroll bar position on a dynamically sized page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a page with dynamically load data but when I go to another link and back to the same page , I can not back to the same scroll

Comment: https://nikolafilm.com/world     this my website

Comment: make a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

Save the scroll position when the user scrolls.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem('scroll_pos', scrollY);
});
```

Reload the last known scroll position when the page loads.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('scroll_pos') || 0);
});
```

You might want to implement something to delete that scroll position value after a certain amount of time has passed otherwise it will always scroll to the last known position every time that pages is loaded.